# Using Postman, can initial setup requests be in the same collection as a data file?

Tags: postman

Using **Postman data files** for the first time - I have a couple of setup requests / tests to carry out (authentication, clear cache etc.) *just once* before a data file gets executed against my functional requests.

Do the setup requests need to be in a separate collection to avoid them being executed against every row of my data file, or can I combine them in the same collection somehow while ensuring (a) they are only run once and (b) they are run before the data file is executed?

We also want to execute this via Newman for our nightly automated run.

Answer (score 0):

I would put all requests in one collection.

The very first script being the setup script.

Then in the pre-request script of the setup, you can check `pm.info.iteration:Number` to get the number of the current iteration and if it's not the first one, use `pm.setNextRequest("2nd request")` to call the 2nd request in the collection.

Comment: Thanks @Christian-Baumann! There is so much about `pm` object that I do not know ... I will try out this solution today.

Comment: The [Postman JavaScript reference](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/) is a good starting point for that.

Comment: Almost there - by this code being in the pre-request - it still executes this specific  request. Is there an alternative to `setNextRequest` that actually skips *the current* request?

Comment: Ah, forgot about that. setNextRequest is executed at the very end of the current request.